# JSON language server in QtCreator

Tags: json, qt-creator, language-server-protocol

I don't seem to be able to get a language server for JSON (not tried others) working in QtCreator.

I downloaded vscode-json-langageserver and set it up in QtCreator options... Language client:

```
*.json, 
startup behaviour: "Requires an Open File"
Executable: /usr/bin/node
Arguments: /home/netherda/node_modules/vscode-json-languageserver --node-ipc
```

I have set up MIME types, and tried various combinations. The capabilities field  reports "Available after server was[sic] initialized" and I see no difference when I open a json file.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used that language server before but I've used the python one that [Qt use in their example](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtcreator-master/creator-language-servers.html). I thought I'd take a look to see if it worked on my machine.

I'm using the following Qt Creator:

```
Qt Creator 4.10.0
Based on Qt 5.13.1 (GCC 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6), 64 bit)
Built on Sep 4 2019 04:47:37
From revision 9b7bab7d35
```

And I installed the plug in using [these instructions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-json-languageservice):

```
npm install --save vscode-json-languageservice
```

The python service they use in the example communicates via stdio so I tried using that instead e.g.

```
*.json, 
startup behaviour: "Requires an Open File"
Executable: /usr/bin/node
Arguments: /home/netherda/node_modules/vscode-json-languageserver --stdio
```

When I tried this out locally it appeared to do something. Unfortunately the something was to produce an initialisation error:

```
Cannot read property 'provideFormatter' of undefined
```

I'm not sure whether the server or qt-creator is at fault (or a mix of both) but it appears to be caused by qt-creator not supplying any initialisation options and the server code assuming they'll be there.

I came up with a fix locally which is to check that initialisation options exist before trying to use them and that seems to work. I'm going to open up a pull request on [vscode](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode) for a suggested fix.

In the mean time, if you see the same problem and are happy to use my idea, you can edit 2 lines of the **connection.onInitialize((params) =>** callback inside **jsonServerMain.(js/ts)** (In the version my package manger supplied it's js but it appears to be changed to [ts in the latest](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/json-language-features/server/src/jsonServerMain.ts#L123), the problem seems to exist whichever version you'd use though...)

e.g. on my machine it's: **node_modules/vscode-json-languageserver/out/jsonServerMain.js**

I changed:

```
dynamicFormatterRegistration = getClientCapability('textDocument.rangeFormatting.dynamicRegistration', false) && (typeof params.initializationOptions.provideFormatter !== 'boolean');
```

to be

```
dynamicFormatterRegistration = getClientCapability('textDocument.rangeFormatting.dynamicRegistration', false) && ((params.initializationOptions) && typeof params.initializationOptions.provideFormatter !== 'boolean');
```

and in the capabilities object def I changed:

```
documentRangeFormattingProvider: params.initializationOptions.provideFormatter === true
```

to be

```
documentRangeFormattingProvider: (params.initializationOptions) ? params.initializationOptions.provideFormatter === true : false
```

You can tell it's working if the capabilities field is populated. (Try changing the startup behaviour to "Always on" whilst testing):

[image: Populated capabilities field]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this. I followed your instruction, then opened a .json file. I get:   `LanguageClient JSON: Error: Notification handler 'textDocument/didOpen' failed with message: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined  
LanguageClient JSON: Error: Notification handler 'textDocument/didChange' failed with message: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined  
LanguageClient JSON: Error: Notification handler 'textDocument/didChange' failed with message: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined`

Comment: That's a new one for me. Did the capabilities field update in the menu?